# pgfplots: Filling a region between two curves in 3D

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I'm trying to create a figure to help explain different types of line integrals. This involves a curve in 3 dimensions (the thick line), the curve in the x-y plane that it follows (the dashed line), and the projections in the xz and yz planes. I would like to have the area between the thick black curve and the dashed curved filled, but whatever I try I get either no fill or the fill shown in the figure below. I've tried the **fillbetween** package, but that doesn't seem to work with 3D plots. Any thoughts on how to achieve this are gratefully appreciated.

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
            declare function={mynorm(\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-    (x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));}
            ]

\begin{axis}[
        view={135}{45},
        enlargelimits=false,
        grid=major,
        domain=0:16,
        y domain=0:4,
        samples=50,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        ]

    \addplot3 [domain=0:4, samples=50, samples y=0, smooth, fill=gray!60] (x,0,{mynorm(1,0.5)}) \closedcycle;
    \addplot3 [domain=0:16, samples=50, samples y=0, smooth, fill=gray!60] (0,x,{mynorm(1,0.5)}) \closedcycle;

    \addplot3 [thick,domain=0:4, samples=50, samples y=0, smooth, fill=gray] (x,x^2,{mynorm(1.0,0.5)});
    \addplot3 [domain=0:4, samples=50, samples y=0, smooth, dashed] (x,x^2,0);

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces the result

[image]

Comment: As nobody welcomed you when you asked your first question: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `fillbetween` does work for me. You only have to put the shapes on different layers in order to make them visible and not cover each other:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={mynorm(\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-    (x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));}
  ]

\begin{axis}[
    view={135}{45},
    enlargelimits=false,
    grid=major,
    domain=0:16,
    y domain=0:4,
    samples=50,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
  ]

  \addplot3 [domain=0:4, samples=50, samples y=0, smooth, fill=gray!60, on layer=axis grid] (x,0,{mynorm(1,0.5)}) \closedcycle;
  \addplot3 [domain=0:16, samples=50, samples y=0, smooth, fill=gray!60, on layer=axis grid] (0,x,{mynorm(1,0.5)}) \closedcycle;

  \addplot3 [name path=A,thick,domain=0:4, samples=50, samples y=0, smooth] (x,x^2,{mynorm(1.0,0.5)});
  \addplot3 [name path=B,domain=0:4, samples=50, samples y=0, smooth, dashed, on layer=axis foreground] (x,x^2,0);
  \addplot3 [gray] fill between [of=A and B];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, knock me down with a feather! I had tried multiple versions of that, but it never worked. I must have been missing something somewhere....Many thanks.

Comment: It somehow has to do with the different layers. I had to try several times before it actually worked. I had to put the projections on the same layer as the grid, so now the ticks lie above the projections.